# How to Convert UTF-8 to hexadecimal equivalent in Java?

Tags: utf-8, hex

I am trying to read a set of characters from a notepad file which is in a UTF-8 format and convert it to a hexadecimal string. I tried converting it to byte array and then parsing it to Int and to hex value. Also I tried changing the string to char array and parsing it to int but in both the cases I did not get the expected value.

Comment: What value did you expect, what did you get, and what does your code look like?

Comment: My code looks something like this: String contents = "contains the utf-8 string"; byte[] bytes = contents.getBytes("UTF-8"); for(byte : eachByte bytes) int value = (int) byte; Integer.toHexString(value); For few characters I am getting the right value I am using the hex editor to check the value.